# How to call redux dispatch inside an aysnc function as the body of function?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, axios, jwt

i have this API helper in my react native code, but i want the user to logout everytime the jwtt token isExpired

this is the code

```
  const apiHelper = async (key, payload) => {
  let token = await getToken();
  //to get the currentToken from AsyncStorage
  const isTokenExpired = checkToken(token);
  //checkToken return a boolean (it is work just fine)

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  if (isTokenExpired) {
    dispatch(logout());
    return;
  }

  //... rest of the API Helper
}
```

result of this code =>

> invalid hook call : Hooks can only be called inside the body of a
> function component.

what have i tried is calling the redux directly from the store

```
import store from './src/redux/store';
const apiHelper = async (key, payload) => {
  let token = await getToken();
  //to get the currentToken from AsyncStorage
  const isTokenExpired = checkToken(token);
  //checkToken return a boolean (it is work just fine)

  let redux = store();

  if (isTokenExpired) {
    const { store } = redux;
    store.dispatch(logout());
    return;
  }

  //... rest of the API Helper
}
```

this code have no error but the state not changed to logout

this is the logout action

```
export const logout = () => ({type: 'AUTH_RESET'});
```

and the auth reducer

```
 const initialState = () => ({
  userInfo: {},
  token: null,
  isLogin: false,
  showOnboard: true,
});

const Fetch = (state = initialState(), action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
      const { token, ...userInfo } = action.payload;
      return {...state, userInfo, token, isLogin: true, showOnboard: null};

    case 'AUTH_RESET':
      const init = initialState()
      init.showOnboard = false
      return {...state, ...init};

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default Fetch;
```

store.js

```
 export default () => {
  let store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(logger, thunk));
  let persistor = persistStore(store);
  return {store, persistor};
};
```

the logout action and the reducer work fine if i call it using hooks.
but i can't get it work inside an async function.

how can i dispatch the logout inside an async function ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have only one store in your application. This line looks suspicious: `let redux = store();`

Try to import you store and call `store.dispatch(action)` on it.

Comment: If you call the store function from the store.js it gives you a new store. You should have only one store in you application. Try this:
```
const store = createStore(...)
export {store}
```

Comment: and you cant call hook outside of a react component

Comment: What you are trying to do should go in to the middleware. 
const apiMiddleware = (store) => (action) => (next) => {
  if(action.type === "SOME_TYPE"){
    store.dispatch(logout())
  }
}

Comment: I see you have "thunk". Use that.
const logout = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(action)
  }
}
// in react component
const dispatch = useDispatch()
dispatch(logout())

// in the connect function
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    logout: () => dispatch(logout())
  }
}